# Why is MainEvaluate being used when LinearSolve can be compiled?

Tags: numerics, compile, linear-algebra

According to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1096/52) `LinearSolve` can be compiled. However, `CompilePrint[]` shows a call to `MainEvaluate[]` but no warning is generated.  It appears that `LinearSolve` is not compilable, given the presence of `MainEvaluate[]`. But the lack of any warning is surprising. Something more subtle appears to be going on. Consider the following.

```
In[1]:= SetSystemOptions[
  "CompileOptions" -> "CompileReportExternal" -> True];

In[2]:= << CompiledFunctionTools`

In[3]:= v2 = Compile[{{m, _Real, 2}, {v, _Real, 1}},
  LinearSolve[m, v]
  ];


In[4]:= CompilePrint[v2]

Out[4]= "
        2 arguments
        3 Tensor registers
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        T(R2)0 = A1
        T(R1)1 = A2
        Result = T(R1)2

1   T(R1)2 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[LinearSolve][ T(R2)0, T(R1)1]]
2   Return
"
```

There are no warnings generated, but I am not sure why there is a call to `MainEvaluate[]` in the `CompilePrint`.

There is a much clearer warning that compiling fails when one uses options within `LinearSolve` while attempting to compile. Consider the following:

```
In[5]:= v3 = Compile[{{m, _Real, 2}, {v, _Real, 1}},
  LinearSolve[m, v, Method -> "Cholesky"]
  ]

During evaluation of In[5]:= Compile::extscalar: Method->Cholesky cannot 
be compiled and will be evaluated externally. 
The result is assumed to be of type Integer. >>

During evaluation of In[5]:= Compile::exttensor: LinearSolve[m,v,Method->Cholesky]
cannot be compiled and will be evaluated externally. 
The result is assumed to be a rank 2 tensor of type Real. >>
```

Also, `CompilePrint[]` gives the following:

```
In[6]:= CompilePrint[v3]

Out[6]= "
        2 arguments
        1 Integer register
        3 Tensor registers
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        T(R2)0 = A1
        T(R1)1 = A2
        Result = T(R2)2

1   T(R2)2 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{m, v}, LinearSolve[m, v, 
                Method -> Cholesky]][ T(R2)0, T(R1)1]]
2   Return
"
```

**Questions:**

- If `LinearSolve` can't be compiled, why is there no warning in the default case? Is there something more subtle going on (e.g. some parts of the process *are* compiled)?
- If yes, how can one use the `Method` option within the `Compiled` function to ensure that what can be compiled actually is?

Comment: Short [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1096/52): no it can't be compiled.

Comment: @rcollyer I would however like to understand why there is no warning

Comment: @rcollyer But the list says it can be compiled.

Comment: you probably want to rephrase it as "why is no warning produced", since otherwise it looks like an exact duplicate of the question @rcollyer links to above (and will be closed as such, it appears)

Comment: @acl But the list given by Oleksandr and linked by rcollyer says LinearSolve can be compiled.

Comment: Ah, I see it now in one of the secondary lists. I wonder why it's not being compiled, then.

Comment: @asim I think there is something more subtle going on.

Comment: @rcollyer is right; `LinearSolve` can't be compiled. However, you normally don't get a warning because ``Internal`CompileValues`` provides complete type information about it based on the type of the arguments. (Adding a `Method` subverts matching against the patterns given by ``Internal`CompileValues[LinearSolve]``, so you then get the warning.) Appearance of a function in the second list I gave does **not** necessarily mean it can be compiled without needing `MainEvaluate`!

Comment: @Oleksandr R. Thanks. That is very helpful information

Answer (score 21, accepted):

acl already posted the crucial information needed to solve this conundrum (i.e., the definition of `` Internal`CompileValues[LinearSolve] ``), but wishes to delete his post since he had not interpreted it to give the complete answer. Therefore I re-post the following observation along with a summary of what it means.

The input,

```
Internal`CompileValues[];
ClearAttributes[Internal`CompileValues, ReadProtected];
Internal`CompileValues[LinearSolve]
```

yields:

```
HoldPattern[Internal`CompileValues[LinearSolve]] :> {
  HoldPattern[
    LinearSolve[
      System`CompileDump`x_?(Internal`TensorTypeQ[Real, {_, _}]), 
      System`CompileDump`b_?(Internal`TensorTypeQ[Real, {_}])]
    ] :> _?(Internal`TensorTypeQ[Real, {_}]), 
  HoldPattern[
    LinearSolve[
     System`CompileDump`x_?(Internal`TensorTypeQ[Complex, {_, _}]), 
     System`CompileDump`b_?(Internal`TensorTypeQ[Complex, {_}])]
    ] :> _?(Internal`TensorTypeQ[Complex, {_}])
}
```

Briefly put, this tells us that when the compiler sees a function call like `LinearSolve[x, b]`, it knows that:

- when x is a real matrix and b is a real vector, the result is a real vector
- when x is a complex matrix and b is a complex vector, the result is a complex vector

As a result of this knowledge, the compiler is able to determine what type of register is needed to store the return value from `LinearSolve` in these two cases. This is important if further operations are then carried out on the result: in the absence of type information, all subsequent operations on `LinearSolve`'s return value would need to be performed via the interpreter using `MainEvaluate` for full generality, but because the type of the result is predetermined, such operations can be compiled instead. However, since `LinearSolve` is a highly optimized top-level function, compilation does not offer any benefit outside of this scenario, and so knowing the return type has no value if `LinearSolve[x, b]` is the entire contents of the compiled function, since the operation may as well have been performed via the interpreter anyway.

As regards why `LinearSolve[x, b, Method -> m]` produces a message: it is because the definition for `` Internal`CompileValues[LinearSolve] `` does not provide for pattern matching against `LinearSolve` calls when any `Method` is specified. It handles *only* the form `LinearSolve[x, b]`.

#### Conclusion

Just because `` Internal`CompileValues[func] `` is defined for some function *func*, one cannot assume that *func* can be called directly from compiled code without using a `MainEvaluate` call. It simply means that the compiler has information about *func* which it can incorporate into the compilation process as a whole.