# How to do meta-programming inside Compile?

Tags: compile, meta-programming

I'd like to do this: solve some linear systems, compiling the task of getting the building up the matrices from parameter values, and then I have a compiled implementation of LinearSolve. The problem is that there are a huge number of different LHS matrices, and it take time to build them up. I only want to build one per function call. So this is the idea:

```
RHSarray = {{Indexed[arg1, 1], 5.}, {Indexed[arg1, 1], 
   Indexed[arg1, 2]}, {7., 9.}}
LHSarray = {{{Indexed[arg1, 1], Indexed[arg1, 2]}, {3., 
    4.}}, {{Indexed[arg1, 1], 0.}, {0, 1}}, {{1., 0.}, {0, 
    Indexed[arg1, 1]}}}
cFunStraightforward = Compile[{{i, _Integer}, {arg1, _Real, 1}},
   Module[{LHStosolve = {{}}, RHStosolve = {}},
    LHStosolve = LHSarray[[i]]; RHStosolve = RHSarray[[i]];
    LinearSolve[LHStosolve, RHStosolve]],
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];
```

But it creates the entire rank 3 tensor LHSarray, and then selects the ith matrix.

```
Do[ToExpression[
  "LHSarray" <> ToString[i] <> "= LHSarray[[" <> ToString[i] <> 
   "]];"]; ToExpression[
  "RHSarray" <> ToString[i] <> "= RHSarray[[" <> ToString[i] <> 
   "]];"];, {i, 3}]
cFun = Compile[{{i, _Integer}, {arg1, _Real, 1}},
   Module[{LHStosolve = {{}}, RHStosolve = {}},
    If[i == 1, LHStosolve = LHSarray1; RHStosolve = RHSarray1];
    If[i == 2, LHStosolve = LHSarray2; RHStosolve = RHSarray2];
    If[i == 3, LHStosolve = LHSarray3; RHStosolve = RHSarray3];
    LinearSolve[LHStosolve, RHStosolve]],
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];
```

This does what I want. Can you help me do this programmatically? And I would love to get rid of the call to ToExpression too, I just don't know how best to do that.

Edit: I found this, which works. I know there has to be a better way, but it does work.

```
nestIfs[expr_, n_] := 
 "If[i\[Equal]" <> ToString[n] <> ",LHStosolve=LHSarray" <> 
  ToString[n] <> ";RHStosolve=RHSarray" <> ToString[n] <> "," <> 
  expr <> "]"
ToExpression[
 "cFun = Compile[{{i,_Integer},{arg1,_Real,1}},\[IndentingNewLine]\
Module[{LHStosolve = {{}},RHStosolve = {}}," <> 
  Fold[nestIfs, "0", Reverse[Range[3]]] <> 
  ";LinearSolve[LHStosolve,RHStosolve]],\[IndentingNewLine]\
CompilationOptions\[Rule]{\"InlineExternalDefinitions\"\[Rule]True}]"]
cFun[1, {1., 2.}]
```

Comment: Well, are you aware that `LinearSolve` is [not compilable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1101/1871) so you'll gain little speed-up by compiling your function?

Comment: @xzczd I have a compiled version of LinearSolve borrowed from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17774/compiling-linearsolve-or-creating-a-compilable-procedural-version-of-it/91881#91881), which is somewhat faster. And I get a good speed up from all of the complex building up of each matrix (i.e. all the manipulations on what I call arg1.) I could really use some help writing code that isn't ToExpression[string] though!

Comment: **1.** I think using `ToExpression` in poster's definitions is just fine. **2.** Maybe a better fitting question title is "Code generation for Compile"? (I am not criticizing, by the way, I am asking in order to clarify poster's intent.)

Answer (score 2):

How about having `n` separate compiled functions?:

```
cfunclst = MapThread[Compile[{{arg1, _Real, 1}}, LinearSolve@##] &, {LHSarray, RHSarray}]
```

Then just use e.g. `cFunclst[[1]][{1., 2.}]`.

If you insist on using a single compiled function, then a possible solution is

```
toseq = Flatten[#, 1] &@Transpose@{Range@Length@#, #} &;

cfunc = Hold@
     Compile[{{i, _Integer}, {arg1, _Real, 1}}, 
      LinearSolve[sw1, sw2]] /. {sw1 -> switch[i, ##, _, {{0.}}] & @@ toseq@LHSarray, 
     sw2 -> switch[i, ##, _, {0.}] & @@ toseq@RHSarray} /. switch -> Switch // 
  ReleaseHold
```

Comment: Yeah, that's how I have it now. It seemed better to have it all in one function, for distributing it to the parallel workers and loading and unloading, but what do I know.

Comment: @NathanRL Check my update.