# how to Compile user-defined function like this

Tags: compile

the following function can be compiled successfully

```
Clear[mat]
    mat = Compile[{e, kx, {ii, _Integer}, {label, _Integer}, η}, 
      Inverse[{{e - I η,
          -E^(-I kx), 0, -E^(((I kx)/2)), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
          0}, {-E^(I kx), e - I η, -E^(-((I kx)/2)), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -E^(((I kx)/2)), 
          e - I η, -E^(-I kx), 0, -E^(((I kx)/2)), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
          0, 0}, {-E^(-((I kx)/2)), 0, -E^(I kx), 
          e - I η, -E^(-((I kx)/2)), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
          0, 0, -E^(((I kx)/2)), e - I η, -E^(-I kx), 
          0, -E^(((I kx)/2)), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -E^(-((I kx)/2)), 
          0, -E^(I kx), e - I η, -E^(-((I kx)/2)), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
          0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -E^(((I kx)/2)), e - I η, -E^(-I kx), 
          0, -E^(((I kx)/2)), 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, -E^(-((I kx)/2)), 
          0, -E^(I kx), e - I η, -E^(-((I kx)/2)), 0, 0, 0, 0, 
          0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -E^(((I kx)/2)), 
          e - I η, -E^(-I kx), 0, -E^(((I kx)/2)), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
          0, 0, 0, -E^(-((I kx)/2)), 0, -E^(I kx), 
          e - I η, -E^(-((I kx)/2)), 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
          0, 0, -E^(((I kx)/2)), e - I η, -E^(-I kx), 
          0, -E^(((I kx)/2))}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -E^(-((I kx)/2)), 
          0, -E^(I kx), e - I η, -E^(-((I kx)/2)), 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -E^(((I kx)/2)), 
          e - I η, -E^(-I kx)}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
          0, -E^(-((I kx)/2)), 0, -E^(I kx), e - I η}}][[
       2*(ii - 1) + label, 2*(ii - 1) + label]], CompilationTarget -> "C"]
```

as you can see the function calc the one of the matrix element of the inverse matrix.

the result of the above code is

```
CompiledFunction[{e,kx,ii,label,\[Eta]},Block[{Compile`$498,Compile`$502,Compile`$503,Compile`$507,Compile`$508,Compile`$509,Compile`$510,Compile`$504,Compile`$505,Compile`$506,Compile`$514,Compile`$515,Compile`$516,Compile`$511,Compile`$512,Compile`$513,Compile`$518,Compile`$519,Compile`$520},Compile`$498=I \[Eta];Compile`$502=-Compile`$498;Compile`$503=e+Compile`$502;Compile`$507=1/2;Compile`$508=I kx Compile`$507;Compile`$509=E^Compile`$508;Compile`$510=-Compile`$509;Compile`$504=-I kx;Compile`$505=E^Compile`$504;Compile`$506=-Compile`$505;Compile`$514=-Compile`$508;Compile`$515=E^Compile`$514;Compile`$516=-Compile`$515;Compile`$511=I kx;Compile`$512=E^Compile`$511;Compile`$513=-Compile`$512;Compile`$518=ii-1;Compile`$519=2 Compile`$518;Compile`$520=Compile`$519+label;Inverse[{{Compile`$503,Compile`$506,0,Compile`$510,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{Compile`$513,Compile`$503,Compile`$516,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,Compile`$510,Compile`$503,Compile`$506,0,Compile`$510,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{Compile`$516,0,Compile`$513,Compile`$503,Compile`$516,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,Compile`$510,Compile`$503,Compile`$506,0,Compile`$510,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,Compile`$516,0,Compile`$513,Compile`$503,Compile`$516,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,Compile`$510,Compile`$503,Compile`$506,0,Compile`$510,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,Compile`$516,0,Compile`$513,Compile`$503,Compile`$516,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,Compile`$510,Compile`$503,Compile`$506,0,Compile`$510,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,Compile`$516,0,Compile`$513,Compile`$503,Compile`$516,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,Compile`$510,Compile`$503,Compile`$506,0,Compile`$510},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,Compile`$516,0,Compile`$513,Compile`$503,Compile`$516,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,Compile`$510,Compile`$503,Compile`$506},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,Compile`$516,0,Compile`$513,Compile`$503}}][[Compile`$520,Compile`$520]]],-CompiledCode-]
```

I want to speed it a little, So I defined a function

```
 Clear[invmat]
invmat[m_?MatrixQ, i_, j_] := 
 Det[Drop[m, {j}, {i}]]*(-1)^(i + j)/Det[m]
```

which gives (i,j)th element of the inverse matrix of m directly with calc the whole matrix inverse.

and then I compile the function below

```
Clear[mat2]
mat2 = Compile[{e, kx, {ii, _Integer}, {label, _Integer}, η}, 
  invmat[{{e - I η,
     -E^(-I kx), 0, -E^(((I kx)/2)), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
     0}, {-E^(I kx), e - I η, -E^(-((I kx)/2)), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -E^(((I kx)/2)), e - I η, -E^(-I kx), 
     0, -E^(((I kx)/2)), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-E^(-((I kx)/2)), 
     0, -E^(I kx), e - I η, -E^(-((I kx)/2)), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
     0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -E^(((I kx)/2)), e - I η, -E^(-I kx), 
     0, -E^(((I kx)/2)), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -E^(-((I kx)/2)), 
     0, -E^(I kx), e - I η, -E^(-((I kx)/2)), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
     0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -E^(((I kx)/2)), e - I η, -E^(-I kx), 
     0, -E^(((I kx)/2)), 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, -E^(-((I kx)/2)), 
     0, -E^(I kx), e - I η, -E^(-((I kx)/2)), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0,
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -E^(((I kx)/2)), e - I η, -E^(-I kx), 
     0, -E^(((I kx)/2)), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -E^(-((I kx)/2)), 
     0, -E^(I kx), e - I η, -E^(-((I kx)/2)), 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -E^(((I kx)/2)), e - I η, -E^(-I kx), 
     0, -E^(((I kx)/2))}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -E^(-((I kx)/2)), 
     0, -E^(I kx), e - I η, -E^(-((I kx)/2)), 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -E^(((I kx)/2)), 
     e - I η, -E^(-I kx)}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
     0, -E^(-((I kx)/2)), 0, -E^(I kx), e - I η}}, 
   2*(ii - 1) + label, 2*(ii - 1) + label], CompilationTarget -> "C"]
```

**But `mat2` cannot be compiled because the output is the same. I think at least it should compile the matrix variable in `invmat`**

the output of `mat2` is

```
CompiledFunction[{e,kx,ii,label,η},invmat2[{{e-I η,-E^(-I kx),0,-E^(((I kx)/2)),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{-E^(I kx),e-I η,-E^(-(1/2) (I kx)),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,-E^(((I kx)/2)),e-I η,-E^(-I kx),0,-E^(((I kx)/2)),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{-E^(-(1/2) (I kx)),0,-E^(I kx),e-I η,-E^(-(1/2) (I kx)),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,-E^(((I kx)/2)),e-I η,-E^(-I kx),0,-E^(((I kx)/2)),0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,-E^(-(1/2) (I kx)),0,-E^(I kx),e-I η,-E^(-(1/2) (I kx)),0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,-E^(((I kx)/2)),e-I η,-E^(-I kx),0,-E^(((I kx)/2)),0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,-E^(-(1/2) (I kx)),0,-E^(I kx),e-I η,-E^(-(1/2) (I kx)),0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-E^(((I kx)/2)),e-I η,-E^(-I kx),0,-E^(((I kx)/2)),0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,-E^(-(1/2) (I kx)),0,-E^(I kx),e-I η,-E^(-(1/2) (I kx)),0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-E^(((I kx)/2)),e-I η,-E^(-I kx),0,-E^(((I kx)/2))},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-E^(-(1/2) (I kx)),0,-E^(I kx),e-I η,-E^(-(1/2) (I kx)),0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-E^(((I kx)/2)),e-I η,-E^(-I kx)},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-E^(-(1/2) (I kx)),0,-E^(I kx),e-I η}},2 (ii-1)+label,2 (ii-1)+label],-CompiledCode-]
```

So how to Compile `mat2`?

Comment: You do know, that neither `Inverse` nor `Det` can be compiled down because they are heavily optimised? Please see [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions) to get a list of compilable functions. `Det` is a special case because although it appears in the second list of Oleksandr's answer, it cannot be compiled into a function free of a `MainEvaluate` call. Therefore, all your efforts probably won't lead to a speed up.

Comment: finally someone replied. Thank you!. Well actually I don't expect to compile `Inverse`. What I want to compile is the matrix, you see there is a lot similar term in it. And I have test it, `mat` is compiled, you can see it if you copy the code and paste it into _Mathematica_ and run. But `mat2` didn't compile

Comment: @halirutan I have edited my question

Comment: While `mat` indeed can be compiled, it WILL call `MainEvaluate` when reaches `Inverse` in the code, you can check this with `CompilePrint@mat`. Concerning `mat2`, you cannot compile without `MainEvaluate` because `invmat` still uses `Det` which cannot be compiled, no matter how hard one tries to mask it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling more functions that don't call MainEvaluate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24595/compiling-more-functions-that-dont-call-mainevaluate)

Comment: @IstvánZachar Hello, thank you for your comment. Well, I read  several other post, but still don't understand "mainEvaluate" well. CompilePrint will give `T(C2)0 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[Inverse][ T(C2)14]]` and there is a saying `MainEvaluate tells us that something is going through the evaluator and wasn't compilable`. So this means `Inverse` is not being compiled? What do you mean "invmat still uses Det which cannot be compiled"?? I see both `Inverse` and `Det` were in the second list in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions. I really don't understand

Comment: Let me quote [Oleksandr](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1218/89): "Just because Internal`CompileValues[func] is defined for some function `func`, one cannot assume that `func` can be called directly from compiled code without using a `MainEvaluate` call. It simply means that the compiler has information about `func` which it can incorporate into the compilation process as a whole." According to this, the compiler can deal with uncompiled `Det` or `Inverse` without throwing errors, but not without calling `MainEvaluate`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you face here is that `Attributes[Compile]` shows you that `Compile` holds its arguments. Therefore, nothing will be evaluated per default. So what you have to do is to inject/implant the function definition into the body of `Compile`.

This sounds harder than it is and there are several ways. One of them is (1) holding off the compilation, (2) replace `invmat` with its definition (3) release the hold and do the compilation. I will show you step by step how it works. First we take a *minimal working example* which you should have done in the first place, because I'm sure many users were afraid of the big expression in your example. So here is how you prevent evaluation with `Hold`

```
Hold[fc = Compile[{}, invmat[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}]]]
(* Hold[fc = Compile[{}, invmat[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}]]] *)
```

Now, you take the body of your definition and replace it

```
% /. invmat[m_?MatrixQ] :> Inverse[m]
(* Hold[fc = Compile[{}, Inverse[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}]]] *)
```

And as last step, you release the `Hold`

```
ReleaseHold[%]
```

If you have already a function definition for the code you want to inject, then you can easily use the `DownValues` because this returns the internally used rule(s)$^1$. Using this would look like the following

```
invmat[m_?MatrixQ] := Inverse[m];
Hold[fc = Compile[{}, invmat[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}]]] /. DownValues[invmat]
```

Now you can do the same with your original example.

---

$^1$ Beware, that you might run into problems with the pattern definitions and held code. One simple example is the following

```
Hold[Module[{m = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}},
   invmat[m]
   ]] /. DownValues[invmat]
```

here `invmat` is not replaced, because although `m` is/willBe a matrix, in the code it is currently only a symbol which doesn't fulfil `MatrixQ`.

Comment: Hi, Halirutan! Thank you for your reply!. I was reading mathematica doc today. And found that there exists simpler solution. Just set `CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True}` will do all the work.

Comment: @matheorem You are mistaken. This option only optimizes expressions, it does not include the body of your function in the compiled function. Therefore, you (supposed to be) fast compiled function needs to ask the kernel through a `MainEvaluate` call when this function is called. Please check the output of [this small example](http://pastebin.com/1Hxairjv) to see, that `f` is still called and not replaced with the function definition inside the compiled function.