# Compiling LinearSolve with 2 complex matrices, possible bug

Tags: linear-algebra, complex, compile

Take two complex matrices depending on one variable, for example:

```
m1 = {{1. + 1. I, 1. - 1. I}, {a (1. + .2 I) + 2. I, 0. + 3. I}};
m2 = {{1. - 3. I, 1. - 2. I}, {a (- 1. - .2 I) + 5. I, 0. - 2. I}};
```

Using `LinearSolve` we can find the matrix `m3` satisfying `m1.m3 == m2`:

```
m3 = Block[{a = 1. - .5 I}, LinearSolve[m1, m2]];
Block[{a = 1. - .5 I}, m1.m3 - m2] // Chop
(* {{0,0},{0,0}} *)
```

I want to turn this `LinearSolve` into a compiled function of `a`, for example as:

```
linSol = Hold[Compile][{{a, _Complex, 0}}, Hold[LinearSolve][m1, m2]] /. Hold[x_] :> x;
```

(The `Hold`'s are because I don't want `LinearSolve` to evaluate symbolically)

Now `linSol[1.-.5I]` does give the correct answer, but it does not compile properly, giving the error message

```
CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 7; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>
```

Furthermore, if we either make both matrices real, or replace the second matrix by a vector, the problem disappears, i.e. if we define,

```
v1 = m2[[1]];
linSol2 = Hold[Compile][{{a, _Complex, 0}}, Hold[LinearSolve][m1, v1]] /. Hold[x_] :> x;

m1Re = Assuming[{a > 0}, m1 // Re // Simplify];
m2Re = Assuming[{a > 0}, m2 // Re // Simplify];
linSol3 = Hold[Compile][{{a, _Complex, 0}}, Hold[LinearSolve][m1Re, m2Re]] /. Hold[x_] :> x;
```

Then `linSol2` and `linSol3` work without any problems.

Am I missing something, or is this a bug? I took care that each numeric entry in `m1` and `m2` is a machine precision complex number.

I get this in version 10.4.0 on a mac with OS X.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1101)?

Comment: Are you referring to the fact that `LinearSolve` can't be compiled without a call to `MainEvaluate`? This I know, but I find compiling still speeds it up, i.e. in `linSol3` which does compile, if i make it a pure function instead it is 10x slower for 40x40 matrices. But I'm not able to get this speed increase from compiling in the complex case.

Comment: @Jansen Perhaps you could include your last comment and an example showcasing the speedup you get with Compile in your original question. Those seem important points to make.

Comment: @MarcoB, Hmm it seems I was wrong in my previous comment, I can't replicate the speedup anymore. The issue is still there though, one can imagine it being part of a larger piece of code which needs to be compiled. From [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1193/why-is-mainevaluate-being-used-when-linearsolve-can-be-compiled?rq=1) question it seems the compiler can only determine the output type for arguments {matrix,vector}, but actually it also works for {matrix,matrix} as long as they are both real. Seems there are some definitions missing?